# Version Control for Eclipse that's like Xcode 4's version control?

Tags: git, eclipse, version-control, xcode

I really enjoy Xcode 4's version control with git.  It's all very simple and intuitive and enables me to be extremely productive.  If I modify a file, a little 'M' pops up next to the file and all I have to do is right click and select Source Control > Commit Selected Files... and then I'm done!  Is there something similar for the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an awesome plugin for Eclipse known as [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) . It integrates fantastically with very similar features to what you have wanted.